# Calling PHP function after jquery code

Tags: php, jquery

Dear Firends I have large number of forms on a single web page all of them calls a single PHP function. However what I want is that the forms should call a jquery function and if there is a need then jquery should let it call the PHP function.

I do not want to use Ajax just want to create a PHP function call if the matter can not be solved by jquery.

Each of the form is associated with some data. how ever all the data that is displayed on the page is not available all the time. So what I want is

```
 if (data == available)   { call PHP}
 elseif (data != available) { jquery alert('sory bro');}
```

if data can not be seen now just use jquery to say sorry (no need to check from server). When a page is loaded we know which all pieces of data can not bee seen and are given in different color.

The forms are generated using a PHP loop with each form showing different data but of same type (each form is assocaited with a sort of Article).

All the questions that I have seen are about Ajax. Where as my current PHP code is working fine. all I want it that before making a trip to server if the data is not available the jquery shoould say so. We already know which data is not avaiable so far.

I hope I have explained it

Thanks a lot

**I think I have not made my point clear.. When the page is loaded is already know which data is not available for display and it is marked in seperate color and the div has different arrtibute...*is there some way so that I do not call PHP function for those forms?

Comment: PHP is server side. jQuery is client side. Client-side code CANNOT call server-side code because it's too late. The only way to do that is with an AJAX call.

Comment: So what have you tried and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP executes on the server side. Javascript (jQuery) executes on the client-side. So PHP is completely done executing before Javascript starts executing.

That's why everyone is saying you need to use AJAX. AJAX is a way to make a call back to the server in order to execute PHP code. PHP code **only** executes on the server. So in order to execute PHP, you **have to** make a call back to the server.

Comment: MY PHP code is in place i just want to plug in jquery in between

Comment: Your PHP code resides and executes on the server. Your jQuery code executes on the client. So by the time your jQuery code starts running, PHP is already completely done and no longer processing. So in order to execute PHP code from jQuery, you need to make a request to the server, so that the server can execute the code. That's what AJAX is for. Making a request to the server without reloading the page.

Comment: @ceemabiswas: It sounds like perhaps jeroen's answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

According to your logic, the data is present on the server.
If you want to know if the data is available or not then you have to contact the server right.
If that's the case how can it be solved without sending an ajax request..

You need to make the request as jQuery is a client side code and cannot contact the server directly.. You need the server side script to execute it which is PHP in your case

Comment: Ok Friends I figured it out..

There is a PHP function that generate this page. This function generate all the forms and each form contain one piece of data. THIS DATA MAY OR MAY NOT BE AVAILABLE.

HOWEVER NOW

i changed this function to generate two seperate forms

Form A for the data that is availavle.. calling the PHP function Form B for the data not available calling the jquery function....

Thanks a lot for ur help

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution:

```
 if (data == available)   { $("form").trigger('submit') }
 elseif (data != available) { jquery alert('sory bro');}
```

Obviously you need to adapt the selector according to your specific form / requirements.

Just make sure your form does not get submitted accidentally when you press submit by adding something like `event.preventDefault();` in your function.

Comment: Ok Friends I figured it out..

There is a PHP function that generate this page. This function generate all the forms and each form contain one piece of data. THIS DATA MAY OR MAY NOT BE AVAILABLE.

HOWEVER NOW

i changed this function to generate two seperate forms

Form A for the data that is availavle.. calling the PHP function Form B for the data not available calling the jquery function....

Thanks a lot for ur help